# Excel 2010 workbook sheets sorted by macro

Tags: vba, excel

My (journal entries templates) workbook contains 50+ sheets.
Template layout allows quick upload into accounting software reducing input time.
But each month required types of journals differ.
Sheets are name specific e.g. "Bonus", "electricity accrual","Sales" etc.
First sheet is named "Instruction", and has a macro which lists in col A rows 1 through 50 each sheet in the book in actual order.
**Desired:**
To enter in column B rows 1 through 50, the number order I want eg 
current order is: Instruction         1      This month want:  1
                  Sales               2                        4
                  Bonus               3                        2
                  Electricity accrual 4                        3
**Macro function required:** Look at numbers in column B and sort sheets in that order.

This would stop me having to scan through all sheets each time I want a specific sheet.
Likewise if I later need to review each sheet for management reporting
With grateful thanks

Comment: This is really easily done and you would figure it out yourself in no time if you looked it up using `Google-Search`. If you have no knowledge of vba at all, it's easy to pick up and actually fun to use. I'd suggest [VBA Excel Tutorial](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vba+excel+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

The following will read columns A and B on the "Instruction" worksheet, and then reorder the worksheets (assuming the names in column A are correct) based on the numbers you enter in column B.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReorderWorksheets()

    Dim numberOfSheets
    Dim sheetTargetPositions() As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    numberOfSheets = 50
    ReDim sheetTargetPositions(1 To 2, 1 To numberOfSheets)

    For n = 1 To numberOfSheets
        sheetTargetPositions(2, n) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction").Cells(n, 1).Value
        sheetTargetPositions(1, n) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction").Cells(n, 2)
    Next n

    Call QuickSort2(sheetTargetPositions, 1, 1)

    For n = 1 To numberOfSheets
        If n = 1 Then
            Call ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetTargetPositions(2, n)).Move(, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction"))
        Else
            Call ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetTargetPositions(2, n)).Move(, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetTargetPositions(2, n - 1)))
        End If
    Next n

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction").Activate

End Sub

Public Sub QuickSort2(ByRef pvarArray As Variant, plngDim As Long, plngCol As Long, Optional ByVal plngLeft As Long, Optional ByVal plngRight As Long)
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim varSwap As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cMin As Long
    Dim cMax As Long

    cMin = LBound(pvarArray, plngDim)
    cMax = UBound(pvarArray, plngDim)
    Select Case plngDim
        Case 1
            If plngRight = 0 Then
                plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray, 2)
                plngRight = UBound(pvarArray, 2)
            End If
            lngFirst = plngLeft
            lngLast = plngRight
            varMid = pvarArray(plngCol, (plngLeft + plngRight) \ 2)
            Do
                Do While pvarArray(plngCol, lngFirst) < varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
                    lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
                Loop
                Do While varMid < pvarArray(plngCol, lngLast) And lngLast > plngLeft
                    lngLast = lngLast - 1
                Loop
                If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
                    For c = cMin To cMax
                        varSwap = pvarArray(c, lngFirst)
                        pvarArray(c, lngFirst) = pvarArray(c, lngLast)
                        pvarArray(c, lngLast) = varSwap
                    Next
                    lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
                    lngLast = lngLast - 1
                End If
            Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast
            If plngLeft < lngLast Then QuickSort2 pvarArray, plngDim, plngCol, plngLeft, lngLast
            If lngFirst < plngRight Then QuickSort2 pvarArray, plngDim, plngCol, lngFirst, plngRight
        Case 2
            If plngRight = 0 Then
                plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray, 1)
                plngRight = UBound(pvarArray, 1)
            End If
            lngFirst = plngLeft
            lngLast = plngRight
            varMid = pvarArray((plngLeft + plngRight) \ 2, plngCol)
            Do
                Do While pvarArray(lngFirst, plngCol) < varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
                    lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
                Loop
                Do While varMid < pvarArray(lngLast, plngCol) And lngLast > plngLeft
                    lngLast = lngLast - 1
                Loop
                If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
                    For c = cMin To cMax
                        varSwap = pvarArray(lngFirst, c)
                        pvarArray(lngFirst, c) = pvarArray(lngLast, c)
                        pvarArray(lngLast, c) = varSwap
                    Next
                    lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
                    lngLast = lngLast - 1
                End If
            Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast
            If plngLeft < lngLast Then QuickSort2 pvarArray, plngDim, plngCol, plngLeft, lngLast
            If lngFirst < plngRight Then QuickSort2 pvarArray, plngDim, plngCol, lngFirst, plngRight
    End Select
End Sub
```